# Do I need to convert NSUInteger to size_t?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

If I have the following code:

```
NSUInteger i, count = [pages count];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  Page* page = (Page *)[pages objectAtIndex:i];
  [page setPageNumber:[i unsignedIntValue]];
}
```

PageInfo.pageNumber is a size_t.

Is it still necessary to use `[i unsignedIntValue]` or do I just assign `i` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSUInteger` is not an object (it's a typedef for `unsigned int` on 32-bit or `unsigned long` on 64-bit; `NSNumber`, however, is an object), so attempting to call `unsignedIntValue` on it will probably cause a crash. You can just pass it in directly.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I now see the warning when I try to call unsignedIntValue. Weird for Xcode's autocomplete to suggest that it was a valid call. Oh well. Thanks!